# sudo apt-get update failing in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, apt-get, salt-stack

I am trying to update apt-get in order to install salt-minion but I am getting the error **GPG error: http://repo.saltstack.com precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E08A149DE57BFBE** so I am not able to update and then install what I need

```
root@PrestezaAlpha:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:2 http://repo.saltstack.com precise Release.gpg [490 B]                    
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [55.5 kB]            
Hit http://repo.saltstack.com precise Release                                  
Ign http://repo.saltstack.com precise Release                                  
Ign http://repo.saltstack.com precise/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex             
Ign http://repo.saltstack.com precise/main TranslationIndex                    
Hit http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic Release.gpg                               
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [658 kB]  
Hit http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic Release                                   
Hit http://repo.saltstack.com precise/main i386 Packages                       
Ign http://repo.saltstack.com precise/main Translation-en                      
Hit http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic/non-free i386 Packages                    
Ign http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic/non-free TranslationIndex                 
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex [208 B]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en [252 kB] 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                              
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]            
Ign http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic/non-free Translation-en                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                  
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [55.4 kB]       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [1046 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [284 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en     
Fetched 2351 kB in 5s (416 kB/s)                                          
Reading package lists... Done
**W: GPG error: http://repo.saltstack.com precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E08A149DE57BFBE**
```

Sources list content:

```
deb  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main
deb  http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main
deb  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
deb  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe
```

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/saltstack.list:

```
deb http://repo.saltstack.com/apt/ubuntu/12.04/amd64/latest precise main
```

Do you have any idea how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: have you read this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/127326/how-to-fix-missing-gpg-keys

Answer (score 3):

1. Run `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0E08A149DE57BFBE`
2. And then `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

**First Way:**

Try adding missing key:

```
     sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0E08A149DE57BFBE
```

Then do update:

```
     sudo apt-get update
```

**Second Way:**

If its a useless package then try removing from /etc/apt/sources.list and from this folder:

> cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d